# Least prime divisor of $n!-1$ forms divergent series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> If we have a sequence $\left\{\alpha_{n}\right\}_{n=3}^{\infty}$
> such that $\alpha_{n}$ is the least prime divisors of $n !-1$
> To Show: $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\alpha_{n}} \rightarrow \infty$$

I need help in completing my proof :

$\Rightarrow$ **Claim :** The least prime divisor of $n!-1$ is greater than $n$.

If on the contrary we have prime $p$ s.t. $p \leq n$
then clearly $p \mid n !$
and if we assume $p$ also divides $n !-1$ then $p$ divides $n !-(n !-1)=1$
Hence contradiction.

So the least prime divisor of $n !-1$ is greater than $n$.

> Now how to prove that $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\alpha_{n}} \rightarrow \infty$ once I have shown $\alpha_n \in \{n+1, \ldots, n !-1 \}$.

Comment: am i missing something obvious?  a lower bound for $\alpha _n$ shouldn't help you show divergence, right? (apologies if i've made a mistake...)

Comment: @tomos Yes, you might be right, that's just how I started, getting idea from a similar question.

Comment: Since the $\alpha_n$ are all prime, they form a subsequence of the primes, which is known to diverge, $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{p_n}\to \infty$. Obviously this doesn't help directly, but since this problem implies that result, any proof you give will be expected to be just as hard or harder to prove than that. At the very least, I would start looking into some analytic number theory tools to try to get ideas.

Comment: Actually I might be a bit too quick to jump on that, I assumed the $\alpha_n$ are always distinct.

Comment: Divergent *series* would be a better title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wilson's theorem helps to prove that the sequence diverges : For all integers $n>1$ for which $n+2$ is prime , we have $$(n+2)\mid n!-1$$

This follows from $$(n+1)!\equiv -1\mod (n+2)$$ and $$n+1\equiv -1\mod (n+2)$$

In this case, the smallest prime factor is obviously $n+2$

Hence the sum contains all the reciprocals of the primes $p\ge 5$. Since the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges, the claim follows.